# Detect and refresh Editor when new file is copied into Unity project Directory

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making an Editor plugin that automatically copies a file from another folder that is outside the project directory into the Unity project.

I use `File.Copy` to do this and it works but the problem is that, for the file that is copied to be able to show up in the `Project tab`, I have to click outside Unity then click on Unity again. After this, the file will be visible.

Another way to put this is that I have to shift focus to another application then shift focus to Unity before Unity loads and display the file that is copied into its Project's directory.

How can I make the file show up in the `Project tab` once I execute `File.Copy` without clicking outside Unity and inside the Unity Editor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this: [AssetDatabase.Refresh()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.Refresh.html)

Comment: Can't believe how much time I spent on this. Thanks.

Comment: It works but very slow as it has to re-import everything? Not sure about that. The fix is to provide the second parameter. It is now fast even though I can't explain why. `AssetDatabase.Refresh(ImportAssetOptions.ForceUpdate);`

Comment: Well, sometimes Unity's docs suck :( https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ImportAssetOptions.ForceUpdate.html